# Reading message fails if client not inside a while loop

Tags: java, networking, tcp

I have a small TCP server and client where the server is performing inside a while(true) loop meanwhile my client isn't. However when i send a message from the client to the server, the server isn't able to read it. Below is the code and error:

SERVER:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

    System.out.println("[SERVER]: Server launched on port " + port);

    while (true) { // the while loop makes the server continuously accept client request
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        
        System.out.println("New client connected: " + clientSocket);

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        
        
    }
```

CLIENT:

```
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9101);
    
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    
    out.println("lol");
```

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

The error occurs when we try to read data in the server. With all that being said, if i surround the out.println() method in the client in a while(true) loop the error goes away and the code works fine. So i'm wondering why the i get this exception when the server is inside an infinite loop but the client isn't.

Comment: Please, provide the stacktrace to see where the exception is thrown.
It looks like it is thrown after print method because you don't close the socket connection. Try adding socket.close() in the end.

Comment: Please try to call out.flush() after the println to actually send the written data.